# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de filtrar elementos por su tipo con filter?

Tags: php, javascript, filtro

Este es el html o la estructura, aquí cada uno de los elementos en este caso los inputs tienen la clase servicios, posteriormente la lógica esta en el javascript:

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
         <?php 
            $_resultPromo  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `proy_servicios` where estatus=1 ORDER BY id");
            if (mysql_num_rows($_resultPromo) != 0) {
            while ($row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($_resultPromo)){
            $idDcto =  $row["id"];
            $descDcto =  $row["servicio"];
            ?>
         <div class="span1">
            <span class="formwrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" class="servicios" name="chk<?echo $idDcto;?>" id="chk<?echo $idDcto;?>" /><? echo $descDcto;?>
            </span>
         </div>
         <?php
            }
            }
            mysql_free_result($_resultPromo);
            ?>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span1"><label>Pa&iacute;s:</label></div>
         <div class="span2">
            <span class="formwrapper">
            <select class="servicios" name="cboPais" id="cboPais" style="width:100%;font-size:10px;" onchange="fnLoadStates(this.value,0)" >
            <?php getCbo("SELECT id , nombre descripcion FROM proy_pais WHERE estatus = 1 ORDER BY nombre",$_pais); ?>
            </select>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="span1"><label>Estado:</label></div>
         <div class="span2">
            <span   id="spanEstado" name="spanEstado" class="formwrapper">
               <select class="servicios" name="cboEstado" id="cboEstado" style="width:100%;font-size:10px;" onchange="fnLoadStates(this.value,0)" >
                  <option value='0' />.::Seleccione::. 
               </select>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="span1"><label>Ciudad:</label></div>
         <div class="span2">
            <span  id="spanCiudad" name="spanCiudad" class="formwrapper">
               <select  class="servicios" name="cboCiudad" id="cboCiudad" style="width:100%;font-size:10px;" onchange="fnLoadStates(this.value,0)" >
                  <option value='0' />.::Seleccione::.
               </select>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="span2" style="padding-bottom:.5%;">
            <a onclick="fnBuscarContactos()" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded" style="width:93%;">
            <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i> Buscar
            </a>
         </div>
```

Lo primero que hago es obtener todos los elementos que tienen una clase específica, posteriormente con el filter trato de obtener de ese conjunto solo los que cumplan un cierto tipo.

```js
function fnBuscarContactos() {
    var elementos=document.getElementsByClassName("servicios");


    elementosfilter = elementos.filter(function(elementos){ return elementos.type == "checkbox"})
    console.log(elementosfilter);
}
```

En la consola obtengo este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: elementos.filter is not a function

Comment: Podrías incluir tu `HTML`? Lo más probable es que **elementos** sea un objeto y no un arreglo

Comment: Listo gracias por contestar! Estoy al pendiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `filter` es propia de los Arrays, no de los HTMLCollection, tendrías que convertir este a un tipo Array.

Pero por qué no mejor usar la función `querySelectorAll` con un selector CSS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox].servicios")
```

Se obtiene un `NodeList` con los elementos de tipo `checkbox` que tengan la clase `servicios`

Answer (score 0):

creo que seria mas facil utilizar [documet.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y los [selectores de attributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo):

## ejemplo

```js
// seleccionamos los input
// que contenga la clase servicios
// que sean de tipo checkbox
let a = document.querySelectorAll('input.servicios[type="checkbox"]');

console.log(a);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="servicios">
<input type="checkbox" class="servicios">
<input type="checkbox" class="servicios">
<input type="checkbox" class="servicios">
```